# Import and copy paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the code below to import new data on my workbook and update my template table weekly. I tried it last week and it successfully imported my new data and copy paste the data into my table template on another sheet. 
This week, when I run my macro, it only worked for input new data but it didn't copy paste the new data to the table template. 
Personally, I don't understand why this has happened because there is no error message, even though I commented out "error handle", It works fine only to import new file but the second function of this code doesn't execute.

Can someone review and edit my code please? Do you have any suggestion to write another code to copy and paste my new data to another sheet (in this case inside the table template) ?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import_ClientClass()

 '1. First Import data 1-to-1 to Client Class Table template
    '2. Used Find function to find the matching header from Client Class in New Data
    '3. Copy and Paste the required column from New Data in Client Class    

    Dim lastrow As Long, LastTemp As Long 'lasttemp is "last row for table template
    Const StartRowTemp As Byte = 1
    Dim c As Byte 'number of columns
    Dim GetHeader As Range 'find

    Call Entry_Point
    On Error GoTo Handle

    'pick files to import - allow multiselect
    FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Select Workbook to Import", MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(FiletoOpen) Then
        For FileCnt = 1 To UBound(FiletoOpen)
        Set SelectedBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FiletoOpen(FileCnt))
        ShDataN.Cells.Clear
        SelectedBook.Worksheets("Client").Cells.Copy
        ShDataN.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        SelectedBook.Close

        'locate last empty row in Client Class Table
        lastrow = ShTrial.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'locate last row in the new data
        LastTemp = ShDataN.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'use find function to match headers, since the template could have a different order of columns than the Client Rating Table

        c = 1
        Do While ShTrial.Cells(1, c) <> ""

        Set GetHeader = ShDataN.Rows(StartRowTemp).Find _
        (What:=ShTrial.Cells(1, c).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not GetHeader Is Nothing Then

            ShDataN.Range(ShDataN.Cells(StartRowTemp + 1, GetHeader.Column), ShDataN.Cells(LastTemp, GetHeader.Column)).Copy
            ShTrial.Cells(lastrow, c).PasteSpecial

        End If 'get Header
        c = c + 1
       Loop

        Next FileCnt
        MsgBox "Data imported sucessfully", vbInformation, "General Information"

    End If 'isArray
    ShTrial.Select
    Range("A1").Select

    Call Exit_Point

    Exit Sub

Handle:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
    Else
    MsgBox "An error has occured"
    End If

Call Exit_Point

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, i dont see the declarations of ShTrial and ShDataN. is ShDataN pointing to the rigth sheet ?

Comment: @LuisCurado yes it is, the sheets name

Comment: sorry, but i dont understant. where are u defining that ShTrial is the name of the sheet ?

Comment: @lui they are `CodeName`s, they don't get defined in the code, but rater in the IDE